# jQuery How to check if two or more select drop-down elements have changed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using an ajax call when two drop-down selects are changed.  How do I do that?  This is what I have done, but it works when there is any change to the form, which is not quite the behavior I am looking for:

```
$myForm.change(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: $endPoint,
        data: $formData,  
        success: function(data){
            console.log("success!"); },

        error: function(error){
            console.log("error: ", error)
        },
        complete: function(xhr, status){ 
            console.log("The request is complete!");
        }

    });
```

Also, it doesn't look like this is working:

```
$("#id_dropdown_1", "#id_dropdown_2").change( function () {
     ... same as above 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the `id` of the first dropdown that is changed, then call the ajax when a dropdown is changed afterward that isn't the same one:

```js
var selectChanged = "";
$("select").change(function() {
  if (selectChanged === "") selectChanged = $(this).attr("id");
  else if ($(this).attr("id") !== selectChanged) console.log("Call function here");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
  <option>X</option>
  <option>Y</option>
  <option>Z</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

you used another overload of the jquery function

use **$("#id_dropdown_1", "#id_dropdown_2")** is wrong

**separate between ids** with comma only **without double quotes between two ids** like this
`$("#id_dropdown_1, #id_dropdown_2")`

and don't forget to pass `event` parameter to change function

```
$("#id_dropdown_1, #id_dropdown_2").change( function (event) {
     ... same as above 
});
```

Comment: This only works to check if **either** of them change, not **both** (or at least two).

Comment: I don't understand, this code will **bind** function to **change event** on these **selectors**,

Comment: Yes, but not when *both* are changed. It will call the function if *either* `id_dropdown_1` or `id_dropdown_2` is changed. This means that whenever someone changes only *one* of them, the ajax is called.